# Телефон не видит разрешение android.permission.INTERNET

Tags: android, android-manifest

Устанавливаю приложение с разрешениями

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
```

**Но телефон не видит разрешения android.permission.INTERNET**

не видит - означает, что при установке приложения нужно принять только 2 разрешения `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. И после установки, в настройках приложения. Разрешения видны только на память.

Это всё в android 7.0

**Где может быть ошибка?**

Comment: А какой `buildSdkVersion` у вас стоит. При >= 23 на android 7.0 вообще не должен спрашивать никакие разрешения во время установки.

Comment: Это старое приложение, в котором стоит **targetSdkVersion = 18**. По идеи, все старые приложения должны поддерживаться новыми версиями Андроида!

Comment: Так а в самом приложении доступа к интернету тоже нет? Или только смущает его отсутствие в списке при установке?

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, но у меня как раз таки не просил прав на `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` на Android 7.0.Можно запросить разрешения прям в рантайме, при старте приложения.

Попробуй так же и для `INTERNET`.

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Разрешения получены");

                return true;
            } else {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Разрешение отменено..");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
        //разрешение автоматически предоставляется на sdk <23 при установке;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Разрешения получены");

            return true;
        }
    }

  //Обработчик если разрешения получены..
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);

            //Выполняем произвольный код, подкачка данных  сервера например..
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Разрешения получены");
            CreateHomeDirectory();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `android.permission.INTERNET` не является опасным разрешением, поэтому в рантайме его запрашивать не нужно. Достаточно объявить в манифесте.

Comment: В манифесте об'явлено, но этого права нету в настройках приложения. Да и вообще, что старые версии приложения не поддерживаются новым андроидом??